# Application of Baire Theorem.

Tags: general-topology

Let $B \subset [0,1]$ be a nowhere dense closed set.

$a)$ Show that there exists $s \in [0,1]$ such that for no natural number the point $(s, \frac{s}{n})$ is in the circle $S((0,0),r)$ where $r \in B$.

$b)$ Show that there is an irrational number satisfying the condition from a).

By Baire Theorem, I've shown that the "bad" set, where there exists such natural number, is nowhere dense. I think that it proves $a)$ part. But i have problems with the second part of the exercise.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: For each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ the set

$$A_n=\left\{s\in[0,1]:\left\langle s,\frac{s}n\right\rangle\in\bigcup_{r\in B} S(\langle 0,0\rangle,r)\right\}$$

is closed and nowhere dense; I suspect that you’ve shown this already. Let $$[0,1]\cap\Bbb Q=\{q_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$$ be an enumeration of the rationals in $[0,1]$, and for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $C_n=A_n\cup\{q_n\}$. Now consider the set $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}C_n$.